# В чем разница между паттернами Table Data Gateway, Data Access Object и Repository?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

Визуально, на схемах они очень похожи и имеют одинаковые методы, а при запросе к реализации получаем конкретный объект.

По идее, все они внутри себя централизуют логику доступа к данным. Например, в случае с SQL-это запросы.

Answer (score 2):

Про паттерн **Data Access Object** не слышал, поэтому полез в интернет читать. Действительно, похож на репозиторий, но, как пишут, специфичен для Java и конкретно для JDBC.

Похоже, что **DAO** и **Repository** — два названия для одного и того же паттерна. Я бы использовал название **Repository**, как более общее и устоявшееся.

Что касается **Table Data Gateway**, то этот паттерн описан в книге Фаулера "Шаблоны интеграции корпоративных приложений". У него есть серьёзные отличия от *Repository*.

**Table Data Gateway** позволяет в объектах выразить понятие реляционной таблицы, состоящей из записей. Классически Delphi приложения писались именно так, там аналогом таблицы были экземпляры класса `DataSet`, если мне не изменяет память. При поиске, вставке, обновлении, удалении, **Table Data Gateway** работает с записями таблицы.

**Repository** выражает идею хранилища, огромной коллекции, которая лежит на каких-то внешних носителях. Не факт, что хранилище реализовано через реляционные таблицы, это может быть Mongo или даже XML-файлы. Методы хранилища работают с объектами предметной области, то есть с *сущностями*.

**Table Data Gateway** это классические трёхзвенные приложения, где уровень бизнес-логики (предметной области) обращается к ниже лежащему уровню доступа к данным. **Repository** это приложение с инвертированной зависимостью: на уровне предметной области объявлен *интерфейс репозитория*, а реализация создаётся в отдельной сборке/пакете.

Comment: Т.е Table Data Gateway явно говорит, что этот тип работает с реляционной БД, а Repository может его оборачивать, пряча конкретную реализацию?

Comment: @iluxa1810. Да, репозиторий может загружать или обновлять несколько таблиц, потому что оперирует сущностями предметной области, которые могут храниться в нескольких таблицах в БД. TDG ложится ровно на одну таблицу.

Comment: Понятно. Просто, я как раз Фаулера читаю и у него особый стиль, в первых главах грузить информацией до которой сотня страниц.(Так же и в его книге по рефакторингу было...) И тут полез в интернет за ~разъяснениями и что-то отличий не увидел.

Comment: @iluxa1810, да, Фаулера зачастую *приходится* перечитывать. Мне кажется, он пишет о непростых вопросах, которые приходится укладывать в голове в несколько подходов. :)